# Snake Game, isn't updating properly

Tags: java

I am creating the Snake Game for this project in my computer science class, to note I do not have much experience with Java. It is currently incomplete and I can't seem to get past this problem. I am using JPanels for the snake and the environment. My problem is that when I make a sharp turn with the snake, it messes up and doesn't delete some of the snake's body (This problem only seems to happen when I add an additional body piece to the original 3, so hit E once for this). I use WASD or the arrow keys to move currently, and to add a body piece to the snake I use the key E. I have apples as the body to help me visualize this when I am troubleshooting and rocks to show the last piece of the tail that gets deleted when I move forward.

```java
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;

public class SnakeGame extends JFrame implements KeyListener{     

  //snake stuff
  static ArrayList<Integer> snakeX = new ArrayList<Integer>();  
  static ArrayList<Integer> snakeY = new ArrayList<Integer>(); 

  static JLabel[][] grid = new JLabel[25][25];
  static ImageIcon blacksquare = new ImageIcon("blacksquare.jpg");
  static ImageIcon wall = new ImageIcon("wall.jpg");
  static ImageIcon snakebody = new ImageIcon("snakebody.jpg");
  static ImageIcon snakeheadup = new ImageIcon("snakeheadup.jpg");
  static ImageIcon snakeheaddown = new ImageIcon("snakeheaddown.jpg");
  static ImageIcon snakeheadleft = new ImageIcon("snakeheadleft.jpg");
  static ImageIcon snakeheadright = new ImageIcon("snakeheadright.jpg");
  static ImageIcon apple = new ImageIcon("apple.jpg");
  static ImageIcon rock = new ImageIcon("rock.jpg");

  static boolean up = false;
  static boolean down = false;
  static boolean left = false;
  static boolean right = false;
  static int lastDirection = 1;

  static int newPartX;  
  static int newPartY;

  public SnakeGame(){    
    super("Snake Game Frame");//Make a frame
    addKeyListener(this);
    setSize(500, 500);//Give it a size
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);//Make it go away on close
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(25,25));//Make a panel
    add(panel);//Add it to your frame    

    //Set up background
    for(int i = 0; i < grid.length; i++){
      for(int j = 0; j < grid[i].length; j++){
        grid[i][j] = new JLabel(blacksquare);
        panel.add(grid[i][j]);
      }
    }
    setVisible(true);//Show the frame

    //Set up walls
    for(int i = 0; i < grid.length; i++){
      grid[0][i].setIcon(wall);
      grid[24][i].setIcon(wall);
      grid[i][0].setIcon(wall);
      grid[i][24].setIcon(wall);
    }


    //starting position
    grid[17][12].setIcon(snakeheadup);
    grid[18][12].setIcon(snakebody);
    grid[19][12].setIcon(snakebody);
    //grid[5][7].setIcon(rock);
    //grid[15][14].setIcon(apple);

    snakeX.add(12);
    snakeX.add(12);
    snakeX.add(12);
    snakeY.add(17);
    snakeY.add(18);
    snakeY.add(19);
  }

  public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) 
  {
    int key = e.getKeyCode();

    if(key == KeyEvent.VK_W)
    {
      up = true;
      down = false;
      left = false;
      right = false;
      slither();
    }
    else if(key == KeyEvent.VK_A)
    {
      up = false;
      down = false;
      left = true;
      right = false;
      slither();
    }
    else if(key == KeyEvent.VK_S)
    {
      up = false;
      down = true;
      left = false;
      right = false;
      slither();
    }
    else if(key == KeyEvent.VK_D)
    {
      up = false;
      down = false;
      left = false;
      right = true;
      slither();
    }    
    else if(key == KeyEvent.VK_E)
    {
      newPartX = snakeX.get(snakeX.size()-1); // add a piece
      newPartY = snakeY.get(snakeY.size()-1); // add a piece
      slither();
      snakeX.add(newPartX);
      snakeY.add(newPartY);
      grid[snakeY.get(snakeY.size()-1)][snakeX.get(snakeX.size()-1)].setIcon(apple); // add a body part


    }
  } 
  public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) { //I dont really use these!
  }

  public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) { //I dont really use these!
  }

  public static void slither(){ // add last direction can't be opposite
    if(up == true){

      if(lastDirection != 3){

        snakeX.add(snakeX.get(snakeX.size()-1)); // add a temporary element to the arraylist
        snakeY.add(snakeY.get(snakeY.size()-1)); // add a temporary element to the arraylist

        for (int i = snakeY.size()-1; i > 0; i--){
          snakeY.set(i,snakeY.get(i-1)); // save new position of body parts
          snakeX.set(i,snakeX.get(i-1)); // save new position of body parts
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < snakeY.size()-1; i++){
          grid[snakeY.get(i)][snakeX.get(i)].setIcon(apple); // replace previous body parts with new ones
        }

        grid[snakeY.get(snakeY.size()-1)][snakeX.get(snakeX.size()-1)].setIcon(rock); // replace tail with black

        snakeX.remove(snakeX.get(snakeX.size()-1)); // remove the added piece
        snakeY.remove(snakeY.get(snakeY.size()-1)); // remove the added piece

        snakeX.set(0,snakeX.get(0)); // new head placement
        snakeY.set(0,snakeY.get(0)-1); // new head placement
        grid[snakeY.get(0)][snakeX.get(0)].setIcon(snakeheadup); // add head

        lastDirection = 1;       
      }
    }

    else if(left == true){

      if(lastDirection != 4){

        snakeX.add(snakeX.get(snakeX.size()-1)); // add a temporary element to the arraylist
        snakeY.add(snakeY.get(snakeY.size()-1)); // add a temporary element to the arraylist

        for (int i = snakeY.size()-1; i > 0; i--){
          snakeY.set(i,snakeY.get(i-1)); // save new position of body parts
          snakeX.set(i,snakeX.get(i-1)); // save new position of body parts
        }

        for (int i = 1; i < snakeY.size()-1; i++){
          grid[snakeY.get(i)][snakeX.get(i)].setIcon(apple); // replace previous body parts with new ones
        }

        grid[snakeY.get(snakeY.size()-1)][snakeX.get(snakeX.size()-1)].setIcon(rock); // replace tail with black

        snakeX.remove(snakeX.get(snakeX.size()-1)); // remove the added piece
        snakeY.remove(snakeY.get(snakeY.size()-1)); // remove the added piece

        snakeX.set(0,snakeX.get(0)-1); // new head placement
        snakeY.set(0,snakeY.get(0)); // new head placement
        grid[snakeY.get(0)][snakeX.get(0)].setIcon(snakeheadleft); // add head

        lastDirection = 2;
      }
    }

    else if(down == true){

      if(lastDirection != 1){

        snakeX.add(snakeX.get(snakeX.size()-1)); // add a temporary element to the arraylist
        snakeY.add(snakeY.get(snakeY.size()-1)); // add a temporary element to the arraylist

        for (int i = snakeY.size()-1; i > 0; i--){
          snakeY.set(i,snakeY.get(i-1)); // save new position of body parts
          snakeX.set(i,snakeX.get(i-1)); // save new position of body parts
        }

        for (int i = 1; i < snakeY.size()-1; i++){
          grid[snakeY.get(i)][snakeX.get(i)].setIcon(apple); // replace previous body parts with new ones
        }

        grid[snakeY.get(snakeY.size()-1)][snakeX.get(snakeX.size()-1)].setIcon(rock); // replace tail with black

        snakeX.remove(snakeX.get(snakeX.size()-1)); // remove the added piece
        snakeY.remove(snakeY.get(snakeY.size()-1)); // remove the added piece

        snakeX.set(0,snakeX.get(0)); // new head placement
        snakeY.set(0,snakeY.get(0)+1); // new head placement
        grid[snakeY.get(0)][snakeX.get(0)].setIcon(snakeheaddown); // add head

        lastDirection = 3;
      }
    }

    else if(right == true){

      if(lastDirection != 2){

        snakeX.add(snakeX.get(snakeX.size()-1)); // add a temporary element to the arraylist
        snakeY.add(snakeY.get(snakeY.size()-1)); // add a temporary element to the arraylist

        for (int i = snakeY.size()-1; i > 0; i--){
          snakeY.set(i,snakeY.get(i-1)); // save new position of body parts
          snakeX.set(i,snakeX.get(i-1)); // save new position of body parts
        }

        for (int i = 1; i < snakeY.size()-1; i++){
          grid[snakeY.get(i)][snakeX.get(i)].setIcon(apple); // replace previous body parts with new ones
        }

        grid[snakeY.get(snakeY.size()-1)][snakeX.get(snakeX.size()-1)].setIcon(rock); // replace tail with black

        snakeX.remove(snakeX.get(snakeX.size()-1)); // remove the added piece
        snakeY.remove(snakeY.get(snakeY.size()-1)); // remove the added piece

        snakeX.set(0,snakeX.get(0)+1); // new head placement
        snakeY.set(0,snakeY.get(0)); // new head placement
        grid[snakeY.get(0)][snakeX.get(0)].setIcon(snakeheadright); // add head

        lastDirection = 4;
      }
    }



  }



  public static void main(String[] args){
    SnakeGame game = new SnakeGame();
    game.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);    

  }
}
```

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6MfxU.jpg) are some examples of what I am talking about.

The images can be found [here](https://app.box.com/files/0/f/2916940621).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What did you learn by stepping through this with a debugger?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is with your calls to `remove`.  Each list of co-ordinates can contain duplicates, and the wrong entry is being removed.  You really need to use the other version of `remove` - the one where you pass in a position (as an `int`) instead of passing the object that you want removed.  For example,

```
snakeX.remove(snakeX.size()-1);
```

instead of

```
snakeX.remove(snakeX.get(snakeX.size()-1));
```